# IE 8 throwing type mismatch error on replaceChild()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-8, removechild

I'm trying to dynamically generate an iframe with javascript in order to keep it from populating the browser history.  It works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9, but IE8 throws a 'type mismatch' error on the replaceChild() line.  Here is the function I've written:

```
function frame(ref) {

        var iframeHeaderCell = document.getElementById('frame');
        var oldFrame = iframeHeaderCell.childNodes[1];

        //Create new iframe element
        var iframeHeader = document.createElement('IFRAME');
        iframeHeader.src = ref ;
        iframeHeader.frameBorder = 0;

        //Replace iframe with a new one
        iframeHeaderCell.replaceChild(iframeHeader, oldFrame);  

        return false;
    }
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return frame('products/embo_balloon.html');" class="product">Embo Balloon</a>

<!-- Dynamically inserted iframe goes inside this div -->
<div id="frame">

    <iframe></iframe>

</div>
```

I tried to split the replaceChild() method into removeChild() and appendChild(), but the same error appeared on removeChild().  This made me think maybe my 'oldFrame' variable is the root cause of the function failing, but I don't know how.  I'll also note that appendChild() works with no problem.

I've seen other people have similar problems but unfortunately none were applicable to my situation.  I'd be happy to provide any additional information if needed!

Comment: Have you verified that `oldFrame` contains the element you expect? Have you tried `.children[0]` instead of `.childNodes[1]`? Older IE will eliminate empty text nodes, putting your `iframe` at index `0`. That's probably the issue, so using `.children[0]` should remedy it.

Comment: Have you checked, which node `iframeHeaderCell.childNodes[1]` actually is? I guess, in IE8 you can find the `iframe` from `iframeHeaderCell.childNodes[0]`. Or you can use `children` instead of `childNodes`.

Comment: Using .children[0] solved the problem! I had read about older IE eliminating empty text nodes, so I tried childNodes[0] before, but it didn't work. It sounds like .children is more applicable to what I want anyway. Thanks to Crazy Train and Teemu. (I was going to post this as the answer, but I don't have enough rep...)